# Override /dist or /src for purchased theme - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, frontend, asset-pipeline

I purchased [Mertronic](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/) Bootstrap theme for my RoR app and I need front-end best practices advices.

I'm using Webpack for my js and Asset pipeline for my css

In the theme, there is a /dist folder or a /src

What is the best way to do it?

1) Copy/past the /dist content in /vendor folder. It's what I did and works well but now, how to custom? Where to overide the css and js?

2) Use the /src content with no minified files and put the js files in webpack and css in asset pipeline. Then just need to custom the theme files.

Thanks for the help

Comment: 2 is the best way

Comment: Can you give some details?

Comment: Uhm, exactly what? I'm not totally sure what you want to know

Comment: Why 2 is better than 1

Comment: Because you have a non-minified version, with all the original sources, than it is easy to modify. You can recompile everything at the end.

Comment: @arnaudjnn Just want to know what you ended up doing finally? I am in the same position as you. Can you tell me how you integrated everything?

Answer (score 0):

For the particular usecase of Metronic theme, below is the steps I followed

Copy tools to root of project

Copy src of your final selected demo to lib/src

Open tools/gulp.config.json

Paste this

```
{
  "config": {
    "path": {
      "src": "../lib/src"
    },
    "dist": [
      "../public/assets"
    ]
  }
}
```

Open tools/gulp.config.js

Inside config object, change path and dist to this

```
path: {
    src: "../lib/src",
    common_src: "../lib/src",
    node_modules: "node_modules",
},
dist: ["../public/assets"],
```

Go to tools directory

```
npm install --global npm@latest

npm install --global yarn

npm install --global gulp-cli

npm rm --global gulp

gulp --version

yarn

gulp

gulp watch
```

Now your assets are being built to public/assets

All js/css changes need to be made to lib/src

With watcher running via gulp watch, any new changes will be immediately ported to public/assets

To override styles use the file lib/src/sass/components/_variables.custom.scss

For Generated layout partials

Create your layout using https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic8/demo1/layout-builder.html

Put the contents of the generated layout and partials in the app/views/ directory

Go to app/views/layout and in your terminal execute the shell commands below

```
for file in */*/*/*.html; do mv "$file" "${file/.html/.html.erb}"; done

for file in */*/*.html; do mv "$file" "${file/.html/.html.erb}"; done

for file in */*.html; do mv "$file" "${file/.html/.html.erb}"; done

for file in *.html; do mv "$file" "${file/.html/.html.erb}"; done
```

Go to app/views/partials and in your terminal execute the shell commands below

```
for file in */*/*/*.html; do mv "$file" "${file/.html/.html.erb}"; done

for file in */*/*.html; do mv "$file" "${file/.html/.html.erb}"; done

for file in */*.html; do mv "$file" "${file/.html/.html.erb}"; done

for file in *.html; do mv "$file" "${file/.html/.html.erb}"; done
```

In app/views directory do CMD+SHIFT+F (Find in folder)

Find & replace <!--layout-partial: to <%= render '

Find & replace .html--> to ' %>

Find & replace /_ to /

index.html is moved to application.html.erb as its the root layout

master.html is changed to _master.html.erb

I created a gist on GitHub to integrate Metronic with rails. Maybe it can help you https://gist.github.com/kamalptw/cad9cc02dc7d483aaa8f2e05ed2b8fc6